# Using multidimensional test data to optimize an output

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence, data-science

I am looking for a machine learning strategy that will allow me to load in test data, along with a test outcome, and optimize for a particular scenario to adjust future testing parameters.

(See example in the edit)

Original example: For example, consider that I have a 3 dimensional space (environmental chamber) that I place a physical test device into. I will then select a number of locations and physical attributes with which to test the device. First I will select to test the device at every location configuration, across multiple temperatures, humidities, and pressures. At each test increment, or combination of variables, I log the value of each feature, e.g. x,y,z positional data, as well as the temperature, humidity, pressure, etc.. after setting these parameters I will initiate a software test on the physical device that is affected by the environmental factors in ways too complex for me to predict. This software test can output three outputs that vary with an unknown (until tested) probability based on the logged physical parameters. Of the three outputs, one is a failure, one is a success, and one is that the test finishes without any meaningful output (we can ignore this case in processing).

Once the test finishes testing every physical parameter I provide it, I would like to then run an algorithm on this test data to select the controllable parameters e.g. x,y,z positions, or temperature to maximize my chance of a successful test while also minimizing my chance at a failure (in some cases we find parameters that have a high chance at failure and a high chance at success, failures are more time expensive, thus we need to avoid them). The algorithm should use these to suggest an alternative set of test parameter ranges to initiate the next test iteration that it believes will get us closer to our goal.

Currently, I can maximize the success case by using an iterative decision tree and ignoring the results that end in failure.

Any ideas are appreciated

Edit:
Another example (this is contrived, lets not get into the details of PRNGS)-- Lets say that I have an embedded device that has a hardware pseudo random number generator (PRNG) that is affected by environmental factors, such as heat and magnetometer data. I have a program on the device that uses this PRNG to give me a random value. Suppose that this PRNG just barely achieves sufficient randomization in the average case, in the best case gives me a good random value, and in the worst case fails to provide a random value. By changing the physical parameters of the environment around the device I can find values which with some probability cause this PRNG to fail to give me a random number, give me an 'ok' random number, and which cause it to succeed in generating a cryptographically secure random number. Lets suppose in cases in which it fails to generate a good enough random number the program enters a long running loop trying to find one before ultimately failing, which we would like to avoid as it is computationally expensive. To test this, we first start off by testing every combination of variables in which we can control (temperature, position, etc..) perhaps by jumping several degrees at a time, to give a rough picture on what the device's response looks like over a large range. I would like then to run an algorithm on this test data, narrow my testing windows and iterate over the newly selected feature parameters to arrive at an optimized solution. In this case, since failures are expensive, the optimized solution would be something that minimizes failures, while simultaneously maximizing successes.

Comment: Hi. I do not know if I understood correctly, so please, I could put another example? Another thing, if I understand, see if what you're wanting is similar to PCA.

Comment: PCA selects the attributes most significant for your model that help you to optimize results or to know more about. This help you?